# Create-react-app monorepo use source map for local module

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, lerna, monorepo

I created a monorepo with 2 modules. One is a *create-react-app* and the other is a package which contains *shared components*.

After importing a *shared component* the application starts without any problems. If I debug this in the browser I see the normal code from my IDE for all components from *create-react-app* but the content of the other module is different.

Here is one file from my *shared components*:

```
export class Decision {
    constructor() {
        console.log("I am a test");
    }
}
```

In my browser-tools I see:

```
import _classCallCheck from "/Users/patrick/workspace/react/project_estimation_lerna/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classCallCheck";
export var Decision = function Decision(mainTopic, options) {
   _classCallCheck(this, Decision);

   this.mainTopic = mainTopic;
   this.options = options;
};
```

Is there a way to modify this so that I can see the "uncompiled" code inside my browser tools?